# how to convert selenium page class in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

for example this selenium page class :

```
private final String AccountsFinap = "drilldown2";

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = AccountsFinap)

public WebElement AccountsFinapclick;

private final String DashboadrLinkAccountButton = "link-account-button-persist";
```

convert into like this in xml
`enter code here`

Comment: Why do you need to convert it into XML? Shouldn't you just save it as XML to begin with?

Comment: ok but new framework came in my company so they are using xml file for automation test .  for example if u are reading xpath,id  one java class now i have to read same xpath,id from xml file